# Python, can't assign new string to matrix cell

Tags: python, arrays, string, list, recursion

Trying to solve one task on [leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/word-search/)
Providing picture of code, debug and code itself, but you don't really have to dig into all code, cause problem is on line 3. That's what giving me hard time.
To avoid hitting same letter twice I decided write "." on its place. As you could see on debug it successfully does it on a first run, then when it finds next match, calls recursive function goes to line 3 and throws an error `TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment`. But why? On a first run it was all good, why on a second run it decided throw an error? I don't understand. Even to prevent further errors, I'm passing into recursion a copy of array, not an array itself.

```
def is_word(board, word: str, i: int, j: int) -> bool:
    print(i, j)
    board[i][j] = "."
    
    print(board)
    if len(word) == 0:
        return True;

    if i + 1 < len(board) and board[i + 1][j] == word[0]:
        return is_word(board.copy(), word[1:], i + 1, j)
    if j + 1 < len(board[0]) and board[i][j + 1] == word[0]:
        return is_word(board.copy()[i], word[1:], i, j + 1)
    if i - 1 >= 0 and board[i - 1][j] == word[0]:
        return is_word(board.copy(), word[1:], i - 1, j)
    if j - 1 >= 0 and board[i][j - 1] == word[0]:
        return is_word(board.copy(), word[1:], i, j - 1)
    return False;

def ft_main(board: [[str]], word: str) -> str:
    w_len = len(board[0])
    h_len = len(board)

    for i in range(0, h_len):
        for j in range(0, w_len):
            # once found accurance then check if word could be built
            if board[i][j] == word[0] and is_word(board.copy(), word[1:], i, j):
                return True;
    return False

board = [["A","B","C","E"], ["S","F","C","S"], ["A","D","E","E"]];
word = "ABCCED";

ft_main(board, word)
```

[image: pic of code and debug]

Comment: Note that `board.copy()` is a shallow copy. You're still modifying the original board when you assign to `board[i][j]`. You should use `copy.deepcopy(board)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is in `is_word(board.copy()[i], word[1:], i, j + 1)`: you pass a list of strings `board.copy()[i]` as the first parameter instead of a list of lists of strings. Remove the `[i]`.

Comment: omg..................................................................